# Datepicker in AJAX loaded Modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I can successfully initialize the datepicker every time the modal is loaded. What I cannot do, is to **get it working to complete the input field**.

My logic is the following:

- Write Modal on page load
- Fill in with AJAX reques
- Activate DatePicker

The content to be loaded is a form.

The first time it runs, it works like a charm. **From the second time on, it doesn't complete the input field once it has been selected**.

**It's not an ID problem**, since the input id is created dinamically and datepicker is loaded by class.

This is my initialization code:

```
$.each($html.find('.datepicker'), function(){
    var $input = $(this);
    return $input.datepicker('destroy').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate: -1,
        maxDate: "+1D +1Y",
        onClose: function(selectedDate){
            $input.addClass('has-success');
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see I used `.addClass('has-success')` to easilly locate the input which was updated... but **no input is ever updated from the second load of the modal on**.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this construction of jQuery-each:

```
$.each($html.find('.datepicker'), function(index, value) {
    var $input = value;
    return $input.datepicker('destroy').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate: -1,
        maxDate: "+1D +1Y",
        onClose: function(selectedDate){
            $input.addClass('has-success');
        }
    });
});
```

OR

```
$html.find('.datepicker').each(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    return $input.datepicker('destroy').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate: -1,
        maxDate: "+1D +1Y",
        onClose: function(selectedDate){
            $input.addClass('has-success');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried them both... still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code like this and work properly in multiple field form:

Add this code before loop:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$('.mydatepicker').each(function(){
   $(this).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

And this line is in loop:

```
<div class="control-group form-group" style="padding: 5px;">
  <div class="controls">
    <span class="bi bi-calendar2-minus" style="color: #FF6600;"></span> Input Date
    <input name="myDate$i" type="text" class="form-control mydatepicker" id="myDate$i" required ="true" placeholder="Contoh: 2022-11-25" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" style="border-radius: 3px; padding:10px;"/>
  </div>      
</div>
```